# Login count in php

Tags: php

I have a login script I want if user attempt 3 invalid password then the username associated to them would be disabled or blocked for a day / 24hrs.

Since I make a if condition in php login code where `status=3` alert your account is blocked for a day.

`status` is my database column name which count the value of invalid login of user from 1 to 3 maximum.

But issue is my here that is how I make the `status` automatically count or increase like 1, 2, 3 in user invalid login.

**How to I add this function with my login code**

I have not idea about that. On YouTube there is not any video regards this even in other website.

Stackoverflow is my last hope where someone helps user.

Please have a look at this question and help to create `satatus` count automatic when user inter invalid password.

My login PHP is : https://pastebin.com/QpwDtjBg
**Thank you in advance**

Comment: Use the `$_SESSION` variable to store it?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for a good way to ask a question on SO. What have you tried already? Have you looked into how to increment a field in a database (presumably mysql?) Without seeing what you've tried already, it is hard to know how to help - in such a way that the answers provided are useful to others with similar issues, in the future.

Comment: @Chris might you are employee of stackoverflow but what my mistake. I question which was in my mind and as my view this all english and my language is good.

Comment: These answers will only help you *right now*; in the future, if the link to your external pastebin goes stale then this question and its "answers" won't help anyone else at all.

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna want to use PHP's `$_SESSION` object.

In the code block where you detect bad user/pass combos, add an iterator to the session.

**First, add a session entry to the top of your script (Or wherever you define global variables), for bad_logins, and start your session.**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['bad_logins'] = 0;
```

**Then in the part of your code where you detect a bad login, increment the bad logins by 1.**

```
$_SESSION['bad_logins']++;
```

**This will allow you to then check for bad attempts with an if statement**

```
if($_SESSION['bad_logins'] > 3) {
    // Do something here.
}
```

The script you linked has some other issues you may want to address prior to adding this in though.

Comment: Thank you @ blixxurd I appreciate that you answer me. But I am not get your answer . I don't don't what you want to saying. Req. Could your share your idea via pastebin or this same platform based in my pastebin link. Pls help.. Awaiting 4 your respond

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an update to the field 'status' on the database with 1, 2 or 3, on the IF condition:
if($data == NULL || password_verify($password, $data['Password']) == false) {

And read that same field, when the submit form is sent every single time... if it is already 3, then just skip to the IF condition

if($data['Status'] == "//auto count//")

Something like this (haven't tested the code) and the code should be function based, at least...

`

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$messages = array(
    'INVALID_EMAIL' => "<div class='alert-box warning error'><span>Invalid format, re-enter valid email.</span></div>",
    'ALL_FIELDS_REQUIRED' => "All field is mandatory! case sensitive.",
    'VERIFY_EMAIL' => "Please verify your email!",
    'INVALID_COMBINATION' => "Invalid username or password combinations.",
    'BLOCKED' => "you are blocked for a day. <a href='#'><span>Know why?<span></a>",
);

$msg = "";
$error = false;

$con = new mysqli("localhost", "softwebs_softweb", "test@123", "softwebs_cms");
$email = $con->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']));
$password = $con->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']));

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $msg = $messages['INVALID_EMAIL'];
    $error = true;
}

if ($email == "" || $password == "") {
    $msg = $messages['ALL_FIELDS_REQUIRED'];
    $error = true;
}

if(!$error) {

    $sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users where Email_ID = '$email' ");
    if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
        $data = $sql->fetch_array();

        // Blocked
        if ($date['status'] === 3) {
            $msg = $messages['BLOCKED'];
            $error = true;
        }

        if ($data['isEmailConfirm'] == "0") {
            $msg = $messages['VERIFY_EMAIL'];
            $error = true;
        }

        if ($data == NULL || password_verify($password, $data['Password']) == false) {
            $msg = $messages['INVALID_COMBINATION'];
            $error = true;
            // Update the status + 1
            $sql = $con->query("UPDATE users SET status = " . $statusData['status'] + 1 . " WHERE Email_ID = '$email' ");
        }
    }
}

if($error && trim($msg) !== "") {
    $msg = "<div class='alert-box error'><span>$msg</span></div>";
} else {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login']=$_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['id']=$data['id'];
    header('location: ./account/dashboard.php');
}
}
?>
```

`

Comment: Where from you taken this `$statusData` ?

Comment: Show warning at last `update line` that is = `Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in My_URL` why?

Comment: Pls reply I am awaiting for you

Comment: $statusData is your $data, sorry... It was late in the night ;)

And I can't find any 'My_URL' part on that code, so, this is probably something that you are storing on that field on the database or the field in the database is misconfigured (should be varchar or something like that, and for that error it appears to be int...)

Comment: I am using `set('0', '1', '2', '3')` I also use varchar  but same problem or error was show. I also use `$data` instead `$statusData` but same error was show. Why..Could you run this in your LOCALHOST..?

Comment: I am awaiting 4 u

Comment: You need to show on the code, where the My_URL is, because with this piece of code, I can't find it - so I can't debug it.
Also, the part of updating the status field is in the code above. When you get the $data['status'], you probably have it set by default on the database field, for 0, so, you just need to increment it with +1, then, when it reaches 3, start the blocking.

Comment: I am using 7.1 version of php. Still same problem I am facing same error . Why you not run this in your LOCALHOST..

Comment: I am on your command I dine same as you told me I comment about database setting and set them 0 by default. I done already but same problem.